# How to block other users from writing to my schema in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, privileges

I need to create an user in Oracle (19c) that can only read and write to his own schema - the user cannot see any other schemas (except the default, system schemas).
Also, other users cannot be able to write (create) anything to that user's schema.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default state for a newly-created user - you'd have to grant privileges to allow the new user to see anything else, or for any other use to see the new user's objects (never mind create new ones).

So you don't need to do anything special - you just need to grant your new user the system privileges they need to connect to the database and create their own objects.

The exception is existing users with 'any' privileges, which usually only applies to DBAs. Or if grants to any other schema's objects have been made to the PUBLIC role, which is usually not done.

[Read more about privileges](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-privilege-and-role-authorization.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there any way to prevent the access for that user to any PUBLIC objects, if there are any? Or these accesses would have to be revoked explicitly?

Comment: No, you would need to revoke things from PUBLIC if you don't want them to be available to all users. And them grant them explicitly to any users who do need them (or to bespoke roles those users have).

Comment: @WojtusJ - to summarize, you can prevent others from accessing your schema by simply not granting them privileges.  But you cannot enforce the requirement _" the user cannot see any other schemas "_ because you cannot prevent them from granting privileges on _their_ schemas.  You cannot prevent them from granting to PUBLIC.  You cannot prevent them from granting specifically to you.